# replacing ' and " characters with proper quotation marks

Tags: html, apostrophe, smart-quotes

I'm developing a simple site that doesn't use PHP. This the first website I've programmed from scratch and I'm trying to find the standard method for replacing ' and " (foot and inch marks) with proper apostrophe's and smart quotes . I've looked for an answer but mostly what I'm finding applies to PHP or other backend situations I don't recognize, or it seems to be an article written in the early 2000's. The only thing I know to do is to edit the actual content with the appropriate entity name, but what a pain that would be for a whole site. There must be a trick I don't know about? Did I mention this is my first website:)

Comment: Are you trying to build a website only in html? Do I understand right?

Comment: Most editors have find and replace. That's not working for you?

Comment: Stephen are you suggesting find an instance of ' and replace it with &#8217; That does work but the ' and " are in the markup as well. ex <img class = "Foo">… so it's a pain to sift through.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML editor that allows to load multiple files and do a multiple replace in all the files at once. I use Coffee Cup HTML Editor for such, albeit it is buggy.

Comment: and how do you avoid having your class names changed as you do a global find and replace like that?

Comment: If you are only replacing the quotes, why should you have your identifiers changed?

Comment: If I do a find in dreamweaver for " it includes all my classes on the page in addition to the text quotes.

Comment: Well, any normal text/HTML editor will replace only what you tell it to replace.

Comment: I'm using dreamweaver. If I do a find and replace for quote marks (turning them from "" to &#8220; and &#8221; it replaces ALL my quotes marks, even the class names and javascript in the source code. I don't want to have to monitor the find and replace command for every instance of the " or ' symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more a backend guy when it comes to handle smart typography (I'm the creator of [JoliTypo](https://github.com/jolicode/JoliTypo)) but another tool I know is [Typesetters.js](http://www.opentypography.org/).

You have to install a custom font and a javascript file but you will end-up with a pretty good rendering / typography. I think it only handle English quotes too.